# Java parse csv class

Tags: java, regex, parsing, csv

I am making a class in java to parse in CSV's.  It will read in the file line by line and parse out each field according to the regex pattern into an array, and then print that array.  I put all this together in a main driver below. I looked over everything and it seems to be functional but for some reason whenever I run it, it just gets stuck in an infinite loop and will not cease.  I have looked over this many times and can just not find where this would happen.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 */
public class Csv {

    private  FileInputStream fin;
    private  String line;
    private  String[] parsedFields;


    public boolean isEOL(char n) {
        boolean eol;

        if (n == '\n' || n == '\r') {
            eol = true;
        }

        else
            eol=false;

        return eol;
    }

    public String getLine()
    {
        try
        {
            char c;
            c= (char) fin.read();

            while(!isEOL(c))
            {
                line+=c;
            }
        }


        catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Input Error.");
    }


        return line;

    }

    public void parseFields(String s)
    {
        Pattern CSVLine=Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?:,|$)");
        parsedFields=CSVLine.split(s);


    }

    public void execute()
    {
        String field=getLine();
        parseFields(field);
    }
    public void setFin(FileInputStream usrFin)
    {
        fin=usrFin;
    }

    public void outputFields()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<parsedFields.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(parsedFields[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       try {
           FileInputStream fis;
           fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
           Csv test= new Csv();
           test.setFin(fis);
           test.execute();
           test.outputFields();
       }
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're better off using [SuperCSV](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

```
c= (char) fin.read();

        while(!isEOL(c))
        {
            line+=c;
        }
```

In this part, you loop, adding c, but you never read again. `c` never changes during the loop, and probably is stuck there. You need to have the `c = fin.read();` inside the loop too.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! but for some reason I have a null being read into the line variable.  How would I get rid of this? This is what is being read into my variable:  `nullStudent,Class,Grade`

Comment: What people usually do is this : while((c = fin.read()) != null). IIRC, reading on EOF will return `null`. So this will do the job correctly, I think. :-)

Comment: Forgot to ping you @John

Comment: would I be able to do this? `while(!isEOL(c) && c != null)`

Comment: Try.. `while((c = fin.read()) != null && !isEOL(c))` :-) @John

Comment: Does c need to be an int?

Comment: Because I got an incompatible types error when I put that in.  It said it required an int but found a char....

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm afraid this solution is for String.. Sorry! Could you please add your input in your question, @John ? I'll update my answer when I understand the problem more exactly.

Comment: @John Have you tried to use a String instead of a char, btw?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> readLine(String filePath){
        List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line = null;
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(LINE_PATTERN_REGEXP);
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){              
                Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(line);                
                if(!matcher.find()){    
                    listStr.add(line);                  
                }       
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return listStr;
        }
}
```

Comment: Adding some text along with the code might be nice. Stack Overflow is to help learn, not to help fix the code and that's it. :-)